# SOAP requests with actionscript 2

Tags: soap, actionscript-2

I'm not sure how I can send a SOAP request with actionscript 2 or even if it supports it. I've looked around for a while now and have come up with nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Web service classes](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/00003698.html) for Actionscript 2. I personally do not have have a lot of experience with them and only used them once, many, many years ago in a simple test. So, I can't tell you if they're any good.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm this is on the first google result page [Consuming a Web Service with Flash ActionScript 2.0](http://www.pixeltoys.net/2007/08/29/consuming-a-web-service-with-flash-actionscript.html)

[ActionScript 2.0 Components Language Reference > Web service classes](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00002536.html)